# Converting timestamp to date with timezone

Tags: python, datetime, time

I want to convert a timestamp to a date while timestamp is in a particular timezone. Values I have are like:

```
# timestamp: 1571323748
# timezone: -7
# Expected result: 2019-10-17 07:49:08
```

I know that I can use below line to get date from timestamp:

```
import datetime

d = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1571323748) # date in UTC
print(d)
#or
d = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1571323748) # date in system timezone
print(d)
```

All I want to do is to convert timestamp in given timezone which is `-7`. I have this float number as timezone and not something like `Americ/Los_Angeles`.

So how to create timezone from float value and pass it to a method to get date time from timestamp based on given timezone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it by creating a timezone object like below

```py
timezone = datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(hours=-7))
d = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1571323748, timezone) # date in system timezone
print(d)
```